# Spin Text Items around point without rotate

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to spin text (attached to scroll position) around the central point. What i don't want is the items to get rotated and unreadable. They should rather move on a circle path. Do you have any ideas how i could achieve that?

I'm using Skrollr for my scroll animations but im open to anything.

[starting position](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160523/5xf4u85b.png)

[rotate in progress](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160523/xgyksurf.png)

Comment: Rotate the whole element clockwise and in the same time, rotate the inner elements anti-clockwise.

Comment: works perfect. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought that you could use normal css keyframes to achieve this. You could trigger a class on the parent element on some event and set the animation to occur only when this class is applied. I made a simple snippet to demonstrate. Not sure if this will do the job for your case.

```css
@keyframes circle {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes inner-circle {
    from { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform:rotate(-360deg); }
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size:12px;
  animation: circle 5s linear infinite;
}

img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 275px auto 0;
    color:red;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
}

.div3 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    color:blue;
    transform-origin:50% 200px;
}

.div4 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    color:green;
    transform-origin:50% 200px;
}

div > div {
    animation: inner-circle 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/star-wars/512/darth_vader-128.png" />
    <p>
      This is some text lorem
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/star-wars/512/darth_vader-128.png" />
    <p>
      This is some text lorem
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```